# How to implement mapping in hibernate using annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
I am trying to implement OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping in hibernate but I got error in dispatcher-servlet.xml while adding mapping class.
It return error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
> element 'mapping'. "http://  www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}'
> is expected.
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
            <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
            <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />       
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
          <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
          <property name="annotatedClasses">
           <list>
            <value>com.tushar.hibernate.model.User</value>
            <value>com.tushar.hibernate.model.Sender</value>
           </list>
          </property>
          <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${connectionpool.maximum.statements}</prop>
           </props>
          </property>
          <mapping class="com.tushar.hibernate.model.User" /> <!-- This is the line which return an error -->
          <mapping class="com.tushar.hibernate.model.Sender" />
        </bean>
```

Model Class User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "u_id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    private Set<Sender> userSenderId = new HashSet<Sender>(0);

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_sender", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "u_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "s_id") })
    public Set<Sender> getUserSenderId() {
        return userSenderId;
    }

    public void setUserSenderId(Set<Sender> userSenderId) {
        this.userSenderId = userSenderId;
    }

}
```

Model Class Sender:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sender")
public class Sender {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "s_id")
    private int sId;

    @Column(name = "sender_id")
    private String senderId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;

    public int getsId() {
        return sId;
    }

    public void setsId(int sId) {
        this.sId = sId;
    }

    public String getSenderId() {
        return senderId;
    }

    public void setSenderId(String senderId) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

This are the two class that I want to map each other
@OneToMany for User to Sender
And @ManyToOne for Sender to User

But after running project it return some errors like:

```
Aug 05, 2017 10:20:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/spring-hibernate] has started
Aug 05, 2017 10:20:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/spring-hibernate] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Aug 05, 2017 10:20:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/spring-hibernate] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 05, 2017 10:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 05, 2017 10:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Aug 05, 2017 10:20:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Aug 05, 2017 10:20:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(userSenderId)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4119)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1520)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(userSenderId)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 30 more

Aug 05, 2017 10:20:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/spring-hibernate] threw load() exception
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(userSenderId)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:4119)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1341)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1520)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Aug 05, 2017 10:20:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/spring-hibernate] is completed
```

Above error returns when I tried to do mapping in model without writing mapping property in dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

```
 You have already declared the model classes in the xml:

<list>
        <value>com.tushar.hibernate.model.User</value>
        <value>com.tushar.hibernate.model.Sender</value>
 </list>

You don't need to add the mapping entries, and also this configuration is used by spring and mapping tag in not allowed here. If you are using hibernate.cfg.xml file then you can declare your mappings there(Only if you are not using annotations).

You just need to add @Entity annotation on top of your model classes.
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, I am already using @Entity in model class but not able to do mapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mapping class="com.tushar.hibernate.model.User" />
```

this tag is not present in `<bean>` tag..

If you have hibernate configuration file then use following tag to configure that cfg file in sessionfactory bean of spring cfg file-

```
<property name="configLocation" value="hibernate_cfg_file_name"/>
```

if you remove `<mapping>` tag then may your program work....

try it...

Comment: Hi Navnath, I removed <mapping> tag and error also gone from dispatcher-servlet.xml but after running the project it return some errors which I have mentioned above.

Comment: @TusharKharat above error might be due to  MySQL 5.1.X  .. use  mysql 5.1.35  connector jar

Comment: didn't solve the problem using mysql 5.1.35 connector jar. Still same error come